# How to highlight duplicate columns?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

This is what I have so far but I'm just confused how it works.

```
protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HashSet<string> uniqueValues = new HashSet<string>();
  foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
  {
    // checking duplicate staring at column 1
    string cellText = row.Cells[1].Text;
    // Check if we've already seen this value
    if (uniqueValues.Contains(cellText)) 
    {
      row.Cells[0].CssClass = "duplicate-highlight";
      // This value is a duplicate, apply a CSS class
      // need to add duplicate file to css file standardDesign.cs
    }
    else
    {
      // It's not a duplicate, add it to the set of seen values
      uniqueValues.Add(cellText); 
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get it to highlight while columns that are duplicate.

Comment: Does the code work and you're asking why it works?

Comment: What's your question here? I'm confused

Comment: i got help from a software dev to answer this from working but im wondering what the code does and if its correctly to show my boss. Im finding duplicat values of rows in a spreadsheet and highlighting them.

Comment: What's the confusing part?  Maybe lookup what a `HashSet` is if you don't understand that type of collection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.